# swagger consolidation for multiple microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have multiple microservices, for which swagger has already been implemented. I would like to bring all the api's under single swagger UI. I've followed the following link for doing this. but tried it in maven approach in STS.
[Swagger Consilidation Github example](https://github.com/varghgeorge/microservices-single-swagger)

Here are my different files in the project,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SgtestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SgtestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select() 
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.cloud")))
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.security")))
                     .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Single swagger")
                .description("API to retrieve swagger apis")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }
}
```

My resource provider is as follows,

```
@Component
@Primary
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class GatewaySwaggerResourceProvider implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {

    @Autowired
    private SwaggerServicesConfig swaggerServiceList;

    public GatewaySwaggerResourceProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
        List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();

        List<SwaggerServices> servList=swaggerServiceList.getServiceList();
        for (SwaggerServices swaggerServices : servList) {
            resources.add(swaggerResource(swaggerServices.getName(), swaggerServices.getUrl(),swaggerServices.getVersion()));
        }
        /*swaggerServiceList.getServiceList().forEach(service -> {
            resources.add(swaggerResource(service.getName(), service.getUrl(), service.getVersion()));
        });*/
        return resources;
    }

    private SwaggerResource swaggerResource(String name, String location, String version) {
        SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
        swaggerResource.setName(name);
        swaggerResource.setLocation(location);
        swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion(version);
        return swaggerResource;
    }
}
```

and finally my service configuration,

```
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "documentation.swagger")
public class SwaggerServicesConfig {

    List<SwaggerServices> swagger;

    public List<SwaggerServices> getServiceList() {
        return swagger;
    }

    public void setServiceList(List<SwaggerServices> swaggerResources) {
        this.swagger = swaggerResources;
    }

    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "documentation.swagger.services")
    public static class SwaggerServices {
        private String name;
        private String url;
        private String version;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(String version) {
            this.version = version;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "SwaggerServices [name=" + name + ", url=" + url + ", version=" + version + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

in my application.yml i am specifying the api docs endpoint of different microservices.

```
spring:
  profiles: default

server:
  port: 8014


documentation:
  swagger:
    service-list:
    - name: local-swagger
      url: http://localhost:8085/v2/api-docs
      version: 1.0
```

and my output is as follows,[image: output]

could someone help me out by what am i exactly doing wrong here? i am able to get swager ui but it is not showng any list of api's in that. I am new to swagger, so please kindly review my program.

Comment: What do you get when you navigate to `http://localhost:8014/swagger-resources`?

Comment: I cannot see the output because the image link is broken, but did you find a solution? Because I have tried the same, with every microservice in a possible different host and port, and my output is: Failed to load API definition.
undefined http://localhost:8070/apihttp://localhost:8081/api

Comment: Yes I did find solution. But all the services should be on same host and different ports.

Comment: Hey mike, Could you please share your approach?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a CORS ERROR. Please specify the CORS origin header for all of your Swagger documentation services.

**For Better Approach:**
Instead of specifying micro-services URL explicitly. Register all services to Service register and get all your instance details from it. This is the better approach for centralised swagger.

For Reference:
[Centralized Swagger Documentation](https://github.com/GnanaJeyam/microservice-patterns/tree/master/centralized-swagger-docs)

Answer (score 2):

try this: https://dev.to/eon/how-to-consolidate-api-documentation-in-a-spring-boot-microservices-environment-dgd I was trying to solve this problem earlier, and ended up producing this tool, which is sadly unavailable as open source.

Comment: Nice article, but the source repository doesn't seem to exist.