# Possibility of swagger to document multiple services running on different ports

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have integrated swagger with my micro services built using Spring boot. Its very cool to document each and every operation of the service running on specific port. But here i want to document all of my different services running on different ports under one roof. So in one document i need all the services. Is it possible with swagger? or is there any other way to achieve this . Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSwagger2
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       // System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select() 
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.comcast.BulkSolve.Controller")))
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.comcast.FileProcess.controller")))
                  //.apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.security")))
                     .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Single swagger")
                .description("API to retrieve swagger apis")
                .version("2.0.0")
                .build();
    }
}
```

=================================

```
public class GatewaySwaggerResourceProvider implements SwaggerResourcesProvider{

     @Autowired
        private SwaggerServicesConfig swaggerServiceList;

        public GatewaySwaggerResourceProvider() {
        }

    @Override
    public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();

            List<SwaggerServices> servList=swaggerServiceList.getServiceList();
            for (SwaggerServices swaggerServices : servList) {
                resources.add(swaggerResource(swaggerServices.getName(), swaggerServices.getUrl(),swaggerServices.getVersion()));
            }
            /*swaggerServiceList.getServiceList().forEach(service -> {
                resources.add(swaggerResource(service.getName(), service.getUrl(), service.getVersion()));
            });*/
            return resources;
    }

    private SwaggerResource swaggerResource(String name, String location, String version) {
        SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
        swaggerResource.setName(name);
        swaggerResource.setLocation(location);
        swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion(version);
        return swaggerResource;
    }

}
```

=======================================

```
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "documentation.swagger")
public class SwaggerServicesConfig {

     List<SwaggerServices> swagger;

        public List<SwaggerServices> getServiceList() {
            return swagger;
        }

        public void setServiceList(List<SwaggerServices> swaggerResources) {
            this.swagger = swaggerResources;
        }

        @EnableConfigurationProperties
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "documentation.swagger.services")
        public static class SwaggerServices {
            private String name;
            private String url;
            private String version;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getUrl() {
                return url;
            }

            public void setUrl(String url) {
                this.url = url;
            }

            public String getVersion() {
                return version;
            }

            public void setVersion(String version) {
                this.version = version;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "SwaggerServices [name=" + name + ", url=" + url + ", version=" + version + "]";
            }

        }

}
```

Application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9060

documentation: 
  baseurl: http://localhost
  swagger: 
    services:   
      - 
        name: SolveDocumentation
        url: http://localhost:9003/v2/api-docs
        version: 2.0
      - 
        name: FileprocessDocumentation
        url: http://localhost:9004/v2/api-docs
        version: 2.0
```

## My out put is as follows

[image]

9003 api documentation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGiUc.png)[image]

Below is Resources i am getting for **http://localhost:9060/swagger-resources**
[image]

Below is the swagger-ui getting only one api documentation:
[image]

Comment: Here is the working example. https://github.com/varghgeorge/microservices-single-swagger

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, when I tried to consolidate swagger of multiple microservices. please refer to this example [Consolidated swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636575/swagger-consolidation-for-multiple-microservices)

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for your information. I tried the code but getting different endpoints documentation . Edited my previous question to add the code which i used and also attached the swagger api document what i got as output. Please suggest me what i did wrong.

Comment: You got the documentation for all the services which are running on different ports. Would you elaborate on what your expectation is? @user3853393

Comment: Those all which are there in screenshot are not the services i have developed. I want to get documentation for 2 of the services which i built myself running on port 9003 and 9004 but unfortunately i did not find those documentation included. Please find the application.yml in aove thread

Comment: are those two services running in your local and can you see the swagger json being generated for those two services under v2/api-docs? @user3853393

Comment: The documentation for http://localhost:9003/v2/api-docs and http://localhost:9004/v2/api-docs not included, instead it shows other operations documentation no where i have implemented those operations in any of services(May be they are spring implemented ones)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181972/discussion-between-mike-and-user3853393).

Comment: Here i am getting all the services which i want to consolidate for documentation when i hit http://localhost:9060/swagger-resources. Screen shot attached to main thread, but on http://localhost:9060/swagger-ui.html i am getting one service documentation only.

Comment: There is a drop down above to choose applications. @user3853393

Comment: Thanks mike. Is there any way can we show all those on UI screen with out selecting from drop down?

Comment: I don’t think so @user3853393