# Combining Swagger documentation of different projects into one project in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-ui, content-security-policy

I am working on two projects namely administrator and authentication.
The administrator project is hosted locally on port 3002 and the authentication project is hosted locally on port 3005.
I did set up of swagger on administrator using libraries `swagger-ui-express` and `yamljs`.
The code for setting up swagger in `app.js` is as below -

```
 const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
 const YAML = require('yamljs');
 const swaggerDocument = YAML.load('./swagger.yml');
 const swaggerOptions = {
   explorer: true,
   validatorUrl: null,
   customCss: '.swagger-ui .topbar { display: none }',
   //  customCssUrl: '/custom.css'
   //  customJs: '/custom.js'
 };
 app.use(
   '/api-docs',
   function (req, res, next) {
     swaggerDocument.host = req.get('host');
     req.swaggerDoc = swaggerDocument;
     next();
   },
   swaggerUi.serve,
   swaggerUi.setup(null, swaggerOptions)
 );
```

I am able to call the APIs of the Administrator project since the setup of the swagger is in the same project (same server and same port).
I have selected the appropriate server(localhost) and port(3005) for the authentication project from the list of server dropdowns.
However, when I am trying to call the APIs of the Authentication project from the authentication project, I am getting a CORS error.

[image]

I read the documentation swagger [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/cors/) for the CORS error.
As per the documentation, I added the relevant CORS headers while calling an API and did CORS set up in the backend for the express server as well.

A [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636575/swagger-consolidation-for-multiple-microservices) related question in Java.

Comment: What is the full error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Helen, error message
index.js:112 Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:3005/auth/login/' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.

Comment: Another error on the console -
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:3005/auth/login/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Change `default-src 'self'"` to the `default-src 'self' localhost:*` in the Content Security Policy (CSP). Probably this CSP header is set by [Helmet middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp).

Comment: Thanks, @granty, this has solved my problem!

Comment: @granty, I request you to add this comment as an answer so that I can accept it, it would be helpful for others as well

Comment: Done. I have made a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the message appears in the console(see comments):

> Refused to connect to 'localhost:3005/auth/login' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

this means that CSP is interfering and blocks connects. The fact is that `'self'` covers standart ports only (80 for http:/ws: and 443 if https:/wss:).
Therefore you have to change `default-src 'self'"` to the `default-src 'self' localhost:3005` (with exact port number) in the Content Security Policy. Since `connect-src` is omitted, it fallback to the `default-src`.

May be better to use `default-src 'self' localhost:*` rule (`*` means any port number). Browsers treat `localhost` as safe source (you own device) so is secure enough to allow any ports on `localhost`.
In this case, fallback directives (`img-src`, `script-src`, `style-src`, `frame-src`, etc) will not block any sources downloaded from localhost on any port, what can be convenient in development mode.

Note 1: however, if you need to prepare CSP for the production mode, you can place blocked sources in the relevant directives. In this case CSP will be `default-src 'self'; connect-src localhost:*;` because blocking is observed in the `connect-src`.

Note 2: Quite possible CSP header `default-src 'self'` is set by [Helmet middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp) the latest version of which self-publishes CSP with a default rules.